# Only the last action dispatched reaches reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I have a component where user enters a name, which on changing requires two actions to be taken:

1. Update the component's name field value
2. Asynchronous fetch from the server if the name already exists in the database of the entityType of the

I am using thunk middleware for doing the async work, and then dispatching both actions inside the thunk action creator.

But upon passing actions to dispatch in the thunk action creator, only the action dispatched last reaches the reducer (and hence able to update the state). Why is this so? Where am I making the mistake?

Thank you for your answers!

Relevant code snippets are:

namesection.js

```js
function NameSection({
    entityType,
    nameValue,
    onNameChange,
    warnIfExists
}) {
    return (
        <div>
            <form>
                <Row>
                    <Col md={6} mdOffset={3}>
                        <NameField
                            defaultValue={nameValue}
                            warn={warnIfExists}
                            onChange={onNameChange}
                        />
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}

function mapStateToProps(rootState) {
    const state = rootState.get('nameSection');
    return {
        nameValue: state.get('name'),
        warnIfExists: state.get('warnIfExists')
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch, {entityType}) {
    return {
        onNameChange: (event) =>
            dispatch(handleNameChange(event.target.value, entityType)),
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(NameSection);
```

action.js

```js
export function handleNameChange(
    newName,
    entityType
) {
    return (dispatch) => {

        dispatch({
                meta: {debounce: 'keystroke'},
                payload: newName,
                type: UPDATE_NAME_FIELD
            });

        return request.get('/search/exists')
            .query({
                collection: entityType,
                q: newName
            })
            .then(res => dispatch({
                 meta: {debounce: 'keystroke'},
                 payload: res.text === 'true',
                 type: UPDATE_WARN_IF_EXISTS
            }))
            .catch((error: {message: string}) => error);
    };
}
```

reducer.js

```js
function reducer(
    state = Immutable.Map({
        name: '',
        warnIfExists: false
    }),
    action
) {
    const {payload, type} = action;
    console.log('reducer', payload, type);
    switch (type) {
        case UPDATE_NAME_FIELD:
            return state.set('name', payload);
        case UPDATE_WARN_IF_EXISTS:
            return state.set('warnIfExists', payload);
        // no default
    }
    return state;
}
```

In this case, only warnIfExists is updated, while name field is not update.

Comment: Are you getting the value of `event.target.value`?Did u console it?

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN Yeah, event values are returning fine. The action creator is called too as well, and I can access the values there as well. I dispatch one action and then continue to the next one, but only the last one is dispatched (both actions work fine when run separately, or when they're the last one being dispatched).

Answer (score 0):

Debouncing the entire keypress event handler doesn't seem like a good idea somehow. Doesn't this also block the characters from showing up right away?

Have you tried splitting this in two actions?

1. `UPDATE_NAME_FIELD` should always be dispatched and change the state immediately.
2. `CHECK_UNIQUE_NAME` is dispatched from the same event handler, but is debounced, and then you retrieve the current value from getState before making an api request. Then this would result in `CHECK_UNIQUE_NAME_SUCCESS`, where the reducer handles the result, but also checks if the name has changed in the meantime (so that api responses for old values don't corrupt the state).